# Call platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(@NgModule) returns ASSERTION ERROR Type passed in is not NgModuleType, it does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, pubnub, ng-modules

I have an issue with "platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(app.app_module)" call, the error message is "Uncaught Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not NgModuleType, it does not have 'ɵmod' property".
However I can see this property during debug precess:
[AppModule NgModule **proto** emod property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXG3p.png)

app.app_module is a new @NgModule instance bootstrapping my custom app component. I used TypeScript. **Does anybody have any ideas why such case can happen?**

Also additionally here is source JS code https://gist.github.com/sunnygleason/74e84acd0a03a925ec901594723ce876 
I'm converting it into Typescript Angular CLI project. Here it is
https://github.com/AnatoliYatskevich/WIA

Particular files I changed are:
https://github.com/AnatoliYatskevich/WIA/blob/master/src/main.ts
https://github.com/AnatoliYatskevich/WIA/blob/master/src/index.html
https://github.com/AnatoliYatskevich/WIA/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts
https://github.com/AnatoliYatskevich/WIA/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts

Tool WebStorm, sample formatting from there https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angular2-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The error happens due to erroneous **Module importing** (sometimes it is thrown as "Cannot read property 'ngModule' of undefined" which is also on a deeper level set as "Type passed in is not NgModuleType, it does not have 'ɵmod' property").
So the following procedure (a bit adjusted work for both cases)

**How to find the precise place of the error?**
(especially in complex projects with multiple interdepending modules, like in projects of our team)

> core.js:26131 Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'ngModule' of undefined**
> at **isModuleWithProviders** (core.js:26131)
> at expandModuleWithProviders (core.js:26125)
> at Array.map ()
> at Function.get (core.js:25781)
> at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24103)
> at core.js:24114
> at Array.forEach ()
> at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24114)
> at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:24211)
> at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:27755)

In browser's Dev tools, put a Debug breakpoint at the line where the error occurs (in this case on core.js:26131). The code being there will not help us to much, because it is error logging function (probably `defaultErrorLogger`). Nevertheless, when the breakpoint gets triggered, we can go on our Dev Tools **Call Stack** back till the following code (or similar to it) where the error really occurred:

```js
function isModuleWithProviders(value) {
    return value.ngModule !== undefined;
}
```

The error occurs when the `value` is undefined, so we can put here a conditional breakpoint with the condition `!value`, what will significally speed up the error-chasing process (being triggered only for the erranous module import).

When the conditional breakpoint is triggered, we can go up the Call Stack again up till the `get` method where we can access `moduleType.name` to find name of the module that causes the error.

In **the second part**, we open the module with that name where we can use divide-and-conquere approach, by commenting module imports, until the error is gone.