# ng-packagr Angular 11 Error: Type AppModule does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, webpack

I've just upgrade my solution to Angular 11 and Webpack 5. There are some packages that I build as part of the solution. When it tries to load one of the packages that I've built using ng-packagr I get the following:

Error: Type AppModule does not have 'ɵmod' property.

This error is coming from the Angular Core module. I have tried this with both ivy enabled and disabled.

Any ideas would be appreciated as this is driving me mad and I can't find much on this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60241214/call-platformbrowserdynamic-bootstrapmodulengmodule-returns-assertion-error

Comment: The error appears to be on the AppModule for my local package and commenting out all the modules imports within the AppModule doesn't help. What I don't understand is what is wrong with the module and the above doesn't seem to answer that. I can't seem to find out what 'ɵmod' actually is or means. That's what I need answering really.

Comment: any luck? @jamieLyons